# Python String split() Method + Export ["each pieces split "] in different .txt files

Tags: python, text, split, export, txt

## **Python String split() Method + Export ["each pieces split "] in different .txt and .jpg files with specified path folders for each file type**

Hello, I learn Python and I have to make different actions with a text :

1. Split text
2. Print split text

---

3. Export ["each pieces split"] *contained in print(x)* to different .txt and .jpg files with specified path folders for each file type

---

### Steps 1 and 2 are done :

```
    txt = "This is the first sentence. Then, the second                               
    sentence. And at the end, the last sentence."
    
    x = txt.split (".")

    print(x)

    ['This is the first sentence', ' Then the second sentence',   
    ' And at the end, the last sentence', '']
```

---

### What I try to do :

3. Export ["each pieces split"] *contained in print(x)* to different .txt and .jpg files with specified path folders for each file type

---

*Someone knows how we can make something like that ?*

---

### *Thanks for your help*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach:

```
txt = """This is the first sentence. Then, the second                               
sentence. And at the end, the last sentence."""

sentences = txt.split (".")
path_to_files = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Split txt export'
for index in range(len(sentences)):
    with open(f'{path_to_files}\\file_{index}', 'w') as f:
        f.write(sentences[index])
```

Is this what you want? In the above approach the files will be created based on the number of sentences formed. So if there are 10 sentences, 10 files will be created in a folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I search when I read your description just below of your code proposal but I don't know how execute it ? What I must replace is '/path/to/folder' obviously but is there another information to replace in your code purposal ? I have a SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'. Big thanks @Bhagyesh

Comment: txt = "This is the first sentence. Then, the second sentence. And at the end, the last sentence."

sentences = txt.split (".")
path_to_files = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Split txt export'
for index in range(len(sentences)):
 with open(f'{path_to_files}/file_{index}', 'w') as f:
  f.write(sentences[index])

This is right ?

Comment: It will be nice if you accept the answer if it has helped and solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: The reason for failure is '\' in your path, it should be escaped using a blackslash as '\\', so now your path becomes: `path_to_files = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Split txt export'`, have updated the code with this, please check now you wont get the error you mentioned.

Comment: I guess you can use ```path_to_file = os.path.join(path, 'file_{}'.format(index))```, this will return a string of the path, and you can directly use it in open

Comment: Note that you can use ```for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences)```, which is a bit clearer i think ?

Comment: Yes, that can also be done.. Thanks! However as OP is just started learning Python, just thought of a simple way without using built-in one..

Comment: The double '\\' works! I can open another topic for that. But do you know how to divide the information contained in the sentences to respect the 120 characters per line of codes in the case of many sentences. Only 3 sentences in the exemple but how to lighten the load one line in case of overcharged ? I will accept obviously the answer for sur @Bhagyesh Dudhediya big thanks guys !

Comment: Do you mean only 120 characters off the obtained sentences should be written to every file?

Comment: Imagine a text of 14,000 words instead of the first line txt = "This is the first sentence. (...) And at the end, the last sentence." 14,000 words on the first line. How to do the same things with a split between row 1,2,3 just for convenience ?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how many characters are written per file. How to resolve: "PEP 8: E501 line too long (4392> 120 characters)" ?

Comment: Maybe that comes out to be the other problem than the mentioned in this..

Comment: Thanks! :-) Happy Coding! Pls don't mind pasting the link of your new issue here so that I will take a look at it..

Comment: Thanks I accept your answer as resolved, amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filenames:

```py
filenames: ["path/to/file1", "path/to/file2", "path/to/file3"]
txt = ["Set", "of", "strings"]

for filename, subtxt in zip(filenames, txt):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(subtxt)
```

file1 will contain txt[0], file2 txt[1], ...

This works for txt files, not sure how to do (or even what you try to do) with jpg.

Comment: I don't know the file names because the objective is to name and export them as (file1, file2, file3 etc...) for each sentence split between in '_ _ _' I need to explore Bhagyesh Dudhediya solution but I have a "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" with his solution and I don't know why (Thanks for your answer but I can't write filenames with my hand it will be too long)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You can use `os.mkdir('dirname')` to create a directory. Use this in combination with the answer from @metapod in order to get the dir names from a list.

```
    txt = "This is the first sentence. Then, the second sentence. And at the end, the last sentence."
    x = txt.split(".")

    for i, line in enumerate(x):
        os.mkdir(f'line_{i}')
        os.mkdir(f'line_{i}/text')
        os.mkdir(f'line_{i}/image')

        f = open(f"line_{i}/text/line_{i}.txt", 'w')
        f.write(line)
        f.close()

        f = open(f"line_{i}/image/line_{i}.jpg", 'w')
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've not the level for execute it right now but I will check soon !

Comment: I forgot to mention you have to `import os` before all the code.